# Como passar um parâmetro interpretado no servidor para uma função javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Eu estou criando um controle `ascx` que terá várias impressões em uma mesma página.

Nesse controle, há uma imagem que eu pretendo executar uma função `javascript` ao ser clicada. Por exempo, assim:

```
<asp:Panel ID="divPai" runat="server" >
    <div>
        <div ...>
            <input .../>
        </div>
        <asp:Image ID="btnMensagem" 
                   Class="animated-transition rotate-90-degrees" 
                   ImageUrl="../../Images/bt_proximo.png" 
                   onclick="mostrarAlerta2();" 
                   runat="server" 
                   Style="padding:10px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="div-manipulavel" ...>
        <input ... />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Em um arquivo `js` separado eu tenho todas as funções que eu preciso usar nesse controle e a inclusão desse script está ocorrendo normalmente.

Fiz a importação do script assim:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(GetType(), "scriptsMeuControle", ResolveClientUrl("~/Componentes/Scripts/MeuControle.js"));
```

Esse seria o conteúdo arquivo:

```
function mostrarAlerta(mensagem)
{
    alert('Conteúdo: ' + mensagem);
}

function mostrarAlerta2()
{
    alert('Função acionada!');
}
```

O problema aconte quando eu preciso passar um parâmentro para executar na função, como é o casso da `mostrarAlerta(mensagem)`.

Eu tentei desse jeito:

```
<asp:Image ID="btnMensagem"
           ...
           onclick="mostrarAlerta2('<% =divPai.ClientID %>');"/>
```

Isso não funciona. A expressão `<% =divPai.ClientID %>` não é interpretada e o conteúdo que eu tentei passar é exibido literalmente:

> `Conteúdo: <% =divPai.ClientID %>`

Como faço para passar um parâmetro que é interpretado do lado do servidor como esse para uma função `javascript`?

Comment: Diego, não me lembro muito como se usa. Já tentou usar o Jquery pra capturar o seu valor, será algo como: `$('#<% =divPai.ClientID %>').val()`

Comment: @Marconi Sim, já tentei, mas ele não funciona na chamada da função porque o código também não é interpretado. Pelo que vi nessa resposta do SO que referenciei acima, parece que eu não posso usar esses códigos embutidos em controles que já executam no lado servidor (os `<asp:...` da vida).

Comment: Eu também não posso colocar o seletor jQuery dentro da função js, porque em uma página haverá várias impressões desse controle, a função js seria sobrescrita e iria funcionar apenas para um deles.

Comment: Não é o caso de passar `this.id` para a função? Porque o ClientId vira ID quando o controle é renderizado, não?

Comment: @bfavaretto eu quero passar o id de um outro elemento, no caso `divPai`. Acho que o `this.id` eh iria referir-se à própria imagem

Comment: Pode passar o this e na funçao pegar os dados do avo.

Comment: Aliás nem precisaria passar nada se a função não for chamada inline, o this viria automaticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei encontrando [**nesse post do SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3441872/8093394) a resposta para a minha pergunta.

Em resumo,

> Não é possível usar as expressões do tipo `<%  %>` em controles que são executados do lado do servidor.

A solução que escolhi foi reverter o componente `<asp:Image .../>` para o correspondente nativo - `<img />` - e a chamada foi feita corretamente:

```
<asp:Panel ID="divPai" runat="server" >
    <div>
        <div ...>
            <input .../>
        </div>
        <img id="<% =divPai.ClientID %>_btnMensagem" 
             class="animated-transition rotate-90-degrees" 
             src="../../Images/bt_proximo.png" 
             onclick="mostrarAlerta2('<% =divPai.ClientID %>');" 
             style="padding:10px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="div-manipulavel" ...>
        <input ... />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

As dicas que foram dadas pelos colegas [@dvd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303271/como-passar-um-par%c3%a2metro-interpretado-no-servidor-para-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-javascript#comment615518_303271) e [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303271/como-passar-um-par%c3%a2metro-interpretado-no-servidor-para-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-javascript#comment615490_303271) me ajudaram a concluir a implementação da função `javascript` no meu cenário real.